# Как сделать плавную смену картинок при скроллинге?

Tags: javascript, события, прокрутка

Есть блоки с картинками. Как сделать так, чтобы экран оставался на месте, а картинки плавно сменялись при скролле вниз и возвращались в обратной последовательности при скролле вверх.

**Код**

```js
var section1 = document.getElementById('section1').offsetTop;
var section2 = document.getElementById('section2').offsetTop;
var section3 = document.getElementById('section3').offsetTop;
var section4 = document.getElementById('section4').offsetTop;

var scrollOffset = 300;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

  var scroll = window.pageYOffset + scrollOffset;
  console.log(scroll);

  if (scroll < 500) {
    document.querySelector('.grid-image img').setAttribute('src', 'https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/b47sample3.jpg');
  }

  if (scroll > section2) {
    document.querySelector('.grid-image img').setAttribute('src', 'https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/image-slider4.jpg');
  }

  if (scroll > section3) {
    document.querySelector('.grid-image img').setAttribute('src', 'https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/image-slider3.jpg');
  }

  if (scroll > section4) {
    document.querySelector('.grid-image img').setAttribute('src', 'https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/image-slider1.jpg');
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  img {
    width: 500px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  img {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
  <div class="img-block">
    <div class="grid-image image-1 active"><img src="https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/b47sample3.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="section2">
  <div class="img-block">
    <div class="grid-image image-2 active"><img src="https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/image-slider4.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="section3">
  <div class="img-block">
    <div class="grid-image image-3 active"><img src="https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/image-slider3.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="section4">
  <div class="img-block">
    <div class="grid-image image-4 active"><img src="https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/image-slider1.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @h это значит, чтобы первый экран зафиксировался на месте и не прокручивался вниз вместе с картинками, а сами картинки при этом менялись

Comment: @h с событием скролла или визуальной его составляющей? Он при этом  прокручивается. А визуально - есть ли возможность визуально его скрыть?

Comment: @h а что здесь по вашей ссылке? 4 картинки скроллируются по документу, затем на них наезжает красный фон.. Я, если честно, не понял вашей задумки..

Comment: @h начнем по-порядку фразы "первый экран" и "зафиксировать" вам же понятны - правильно? так вот, картинки должны фиксироваться в первом экране и не скроллироваться, как у вас сейчас в примере

Comment: если бы.. т.е. фраза "первый экран" вам ничего не говорит? а `100vh` хотя бы?

Comment: @h нашел в какую сторону капать  - `Intersection Observer`
https://habr.com/ru/post/494670/
принцип такой же, когда в блоке (а не в окне браузера) картинки сменяют друг друга, но как будто не скроллятся, а заменяют друг друга, т.е. движутся не сверху вниз, а сразу появляется одна, затем на ее месте другая, первая же при этом исчезает. Тем самым на скролл для наблюдателя это не похоже, но по факту это движение колесика мыши или верхнего свайпа на мобиле

Comment: так ? https://jsfiddle.net/ht26s7dL/1/

Comment: @h да, уже ближе, но у меня картинки имеют размеры 240 на 400, а значит нельзя использовать `height: 100vh;` и `pageYOffset`

Comment: почему нельзя? https://jsfiddle.net/ysgrcja8/

Comment: @h у меня поверх картинок есть еще абсолютно спозиционированные элементы и с ними почему-то не получалось.. Спасибо, попробую по вашей методике